# OpenMP - How to parallelize loop with carried dependecies

Tags: dependencies, openmp, nested-loops

What is the best way to parallelize this nested loop with carried dependences?
Konwing that it's inside a function that I call n-times from main.

[edit]

```
    funct(unsigned char*** grid, int n) {

#   pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_count) default(none) \
    shared(grid, n, cur) private(i, j)

        for(i = 1; i <= n+1; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                if(grid[cur][i-1][j] == 2 && grid[cur][i][j] == 0) {
                    grid[1-cur][i-1][j] = 0;
                    grid[1-cur][i][j] = 2;
                }
                else {
                    grid[1-cur][i][j] = grid[cur][i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Main:

```
cur = 0;

for(s = 0; s < steps; s++) {
    funct(grid, N);
    cur = 1-cur;
    funct_2(grid, N)
    cur = 1-cur
}
```

This code runs without errors but returns incorrect result (.ppm file).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If I've understood it's what I'm already doing switching between `cur` and `1-cur`. But if I use `pragma omp parallel for` before the outer loop, it doesn't work. Well let's say it doesn't produce the same result(a ppm file) as of the serial code.

Comment: You'd better show the real code which is causing the problem, what you've posted doesn't have any OpenMP pragmas in it so it's difficult to do more than make educated guesses about what is going wrong.  Or, if not the real code a [mcve] which properly illuminates the issues.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Real code is too long and detailed. However I've edited question and now I hope it's better.

Comment: @Imworsethanyou does the code from my answer work ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Sorry i have still not tested it, maybe tonight. But it seems to be at very high level for me, I'm a student. I would never had tought something like that. I should understand what's happening there before I can use.

Comment: @Imworsethanyou Yes, the code may look complicated, but you must keep in mind that it was generated automatically. Generally, it's not a trivial task to optimize a loop nest with dependences. Additionally, there's a variety of techniques that can be employed. This is why it's way better to have a tool (optimizing compiler) that analyzes the loop nest along with its dependences, and generates output code that respects all of the dependences.

Answer (score 1):

Loop nest optimization/parallelization is the subject of my PhD studies. The below code was generated automatically using my own optimizing compiler. It involves a tiling transformation along with parallel execution of extracted (tile-wise) synchronization-free slices.

```c
#define min(x,y)    ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))
#define floord(n,d) (((n)<0) ? -((-(n)+(d)-1)/(d)) : (n)/(d))
#pragma scop
#pragma omp parallel for
for (register int ir0 = 0; ir0 <= floord(n, 32); ir0 += 1) {
  for (register int ir1 = 0; ir1 <= floord(n - 1, 32); ir1 += 1) {
    if (ir0 == 0) {
      for (register int i1 = 32 * ir1 + 1; i1 <= min(n, 32 * ir1 + 32); i1 += 1) {
        grid[-cur + 1][0][i1] = (((grid[cur][0][i1] == 2) && (grid[cur][1][i1] == 0)) ? 0 : grid[-cur + 1][0][i1]);
      }
    }
    if (n >= 32 * ir0 + 1) {
      for (register int ii0 = ir0; ii0 <= min(ir0 + 1, n / 32); ii0 += 1) {
        for (register int i0 = 32 * ii0 + 1; i0 <= min(n + 1, 31 * ir0 + ii0 + 32); i0 += 1) {
          for (register int i1 = 32 * ir1 + 1; i1 <= min(n, 32 * ir1 + 32); i1 += 1) {
            if (i0 >= 32 * ir0 + 2) {
              grid[-cur + 1][i0 - 1][i1] = (((grid[cur][i0 - 1][i1] == 2) && (grid[cur][i0][i1] == 0)) ? 0 : grid[-cur + 1][i0 - 1][i1]);
            }
            if (ii0 == ir0) {
              grid[-cur + 1][i0][i1] = (((grid[cur][i0 - 1][i1] == 2) && (grid[cur][i0][i1] == 0)) ? 2 : grid[cur][i0][i1]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (register int i1 = 32 * ir1 + 1; i1 <= 32 * ir1 + 32; i1 += 1) {
        grid[-cur + 1][n + 1][i1] = (((grid[cur][n][i1] == 2) && (grid[cur][n + 1][i1] == 0)) ? 2 : grid[cur][n + 1][i1]);
      }
    }
  }
}
#pragma endscop
```

I tested the code with 8 threads operating on `grid[2][N][N]`, where N = { 2500, 5500 }. I obtained a 3x speedup compared to serial execution of your original code.

Comment: Let me know if it works. The results should be correct.

Comment: You were right, it works really great, but as I said it's too high level for my progect, so far from the rest of my basic code. Thanks for support anyway.